# Keyboard covering textView

Tags: swift, keyboard

Text disappears when keyboard exits:

[image]

How do I solve this problem without using library?
I tried some solutions on StackOverflow but it didn't work and they are too old.
Playing with constraints creates a bad view when text changes size.